# Some processes not remaining in jobs list

Tags: background-process, jobs

After a recent workspace reorganization, I am left with a question about the way certain processes interact with the output of `jobs`.

I am running all of my program in the background on one 'Main' terminal, that way I have control and information from them all neatly in one place.  what I have noticed is that when I create instances of some programs in the background, they continue running yet I get notification almost instantly in the console that they have ended.  Programs I have noticed this on are:

- Firefox (only on the 2nd, or higher, instance)
- gnome-terminal (may only be on second, since I already have one open when I try this)
- nautilus (on first instance)

While I can understand the firefox issue, since combining the processes under one parent could make performance/memory sense, I don't understand why a program like nautilus appears to be unable to exist on the `jobs` list for any amount of time, even though the window remains open and the program remains entirely functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, invoking `firefox` a second time will simply ask the running instance to open another window. The `-no-remote` switch can be used to inhibit this behavior.

Something similar happens with `nautilus`: it is used to display the desktop window (with it's icons), so it's already running when you start it.